# Using React-Dnd-touch-Backend Examples

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

im new to this react dnd i want to try to implement this touch backend on my page but it stuck at trying out the example from here https://github.com/yahoo/react-dnd-touch-backend/tree/master/examples/js, my main problem to try it on my webpage i need the index to be a exportable component insted of rendering on the on the dom, this part:

```
var DragDropApp = DragDropContext(Touch({ enableMouseEvents: true }))(App);

function render (lists = datasource) {
    ReactDOM.render(<DragDropApp lists={lists} />, document.getElementById('main'));
}

render();
```

i want something i can export and call from a parent component, how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do, for example:

```
export default DragDropApp;
```

Then in your `App.js` or wherever:

```
render() {
  return <DragDropApp lists={lists} />;
}
```

Then in `index.js`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

Comment: couldnt make it work, shoul i replace `function render (lists = datasource) {
    ReactDOM.render(<DragDropApp lists={lists} />, document.getElementById('main'));
}

render();` for  `export default DragDropApp;`

Comment: you should just have: `var DragDropApp = DragDropContext(Touch({ enableMouseEvents: true }))(App);` and then the `export`.